# Geometric interpretation of partial derivatives

Tags: geometry, partial-derivative

Let us suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a homogeneous function (i.e., $f(tx)=tf(x)$) such that its partial derivative
$$
\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x \partial y \partial z}
$$
is a nonnegative function. What is the geometric interpretation of this condition?

Comment: Do you mean $f(tx, ty, tz) = tf(x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: @WW1 Yes surely

Comment: I think that all solutions of that condition must be linear functions of the form $ f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$ , all the mixed partials are zero for these functions !

Comment: Do you have some arguments for this conclusion?

Comment: You might want to look at [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html) and play around with it.

Comment: @WW1 consider $f(\xi, \eta) = \dfrac{\xi^2}{\eta}$ for $\eta \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0.$

Comment: Such a third order (partial !) derivative (that besides should have had its numerator written $\partial^3 f$).... have usually no intuitive interpretation.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry for the typo, I corrected it